# CentOS 7 freezing

Tags: centos, freeze, hp

I have been running CentOS 7 minimal on around 10 i7-8700 PCs in my organization. These machines are [HP Elitedesk 800 G4 workstations](https://store.hp.com/app/pdp/hp-elitedesk-800-g4-workstation-edition) ([Hardware Ref. Guide](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c06413903)) ([Maintenance and Service Guide](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c06075968)) ([datasheet](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=4aa7-3212enuc)). All work fine, except a couple which freeze randomly, requiring a hard reboot.

I have looked at the var/logs/messages and dmsg but there are no errors which could potentially explain why the machine got hung. I am happy to provide more information if you need me to.

PCs which freeze, and which do not freeze, are using exactly same apps for the same purpose, for local proxy use. I have checked swap usage by running [vmstat](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1160343) with its delay and count but swap usage seems to be not exceeding the limit.

```
# vmstat -a  

procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----  

 r  b   swpd     free  inact active  si  so   bi   bo    in  cs   us sy id wa st  

 2  0      0 14922052 142620 734392   0   0    1    1   107  97    5  3 92  0  0
```

Comment: Do the machines `ping` when they are "frozen"? Do you have a console/terminal that is still working? What does the terminal show?

Comment: No the machine does get pinged when frozen. No, I do not have console or terminal that is still working because it usually happens after a few days, may be once or twice in a month.

Comment: 1. I do not understand "No the machine does get pinged when frozen.". Is that "yes it pings" or "no it does not ping"? 2. But you should connect a screen and a keyboard and look if there's anything displayed. Because that might tell you why the machine froze.

Comment: No It does not ping, I have connected a screen and a keyboard but there was no display at all. I tried certain key combinations on keyboard but to no help.

Comment: @Vipul Bhatiya,  1) What apps are running on these machines; both the ones which freeze and the ones which don't?  2) Are these PCs all loading those apps from a server or from local drives (in which a reinstall of apps may be beneficial)? 3) Still using the factory HDDs? 4) Have you shut the PCs down and swapped memory between the affected PCs and healthy PCs?

Comment: we are running TT edgeproxy app on all these machines, These PCs loading apps from local drives, Yes still using the factory HDDs. I haven't shutdown PCs and swapped memory, in fact no changes from the hardware perspective. All these machines are exactly same spec machines freezing and non freezing both. One thing that bothers me here is that why can't i see any error in the logs  after rebooting when the machine freezes @K7AAY

Comment: Try running memtest86 on the affected machines for a day or so to rule out memory failures. Swapping components (CPU, memory, cooling fans, extension cards) and observing whether the failure migrates with them is also a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Experieced a similiar issue on random identical servers.
Depending on what Kernel you are running you may want to try upgrading to 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64

Fixes the following bugs:

Applications not allowed to consume entirety of allocated cpu quota. (BZ#1770738)
Backport "sched: Fix race between task_group and sched_task_group" (BZ#1778545)